# Why does the database float value is always generated by JOOQ generator as Double instead of Float

Tags: mysql, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

When the JOOQ generator generates the records using database tables, It maps the 'float' type column to Double instead of Float Why?

Database: MySQL,

Create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `product_attribute` (
  `id` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `value` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The various SQL dialects have slightly different interpretations of what is a `REAL`, `FLOAT`, and `DOUBLE PRECISION` data type, and so does JDBC.

[In MySQL, a `FLOAT` type is a varying precision floating point number](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html), so it can correspond to both `java.lang.Float` or `java.lang.Double`. To play safe, jOOQ uses the higher precision representation in order not to lose any data when reading from the database.

If you want an actual `java.lang.Float` representation, then use MySQL's `REAL` data type instead, with the appropriate precision.